# Maven Release Plugin and GIT for other modified mavenized project in git Repo

Tags: git, svn, maven, github, maven-release-plugin

First off, let me give you a background on my git repo and my setup...
For example...  `https://github.com/gitRepo/sqeTemp`.
Within that repo, I have 5 mavenized projects that are not related to each other.

gitRepo/sqeTemp

```
  > Project 1
  > Project 2
  > Project 3
  > Project 4
  > Project 5
```

within the `pom.xml` of Projects 1 (which is the project I'm trying to release, I have the following:

```xml
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:gitRepo/sqeTemp.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:gitRepo/sqeTemp.git</developerConnection>
    <url>http://github.com/gitRepo/sqeTemp</url>
</scm>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <url>
            http://ec2.compute.amazonaws.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases
        </url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>
            http://ec2.compute.amazonaws.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots
        </url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <autoVersionSubmodules>false</autoVersionSubmodules>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I do execute the `mvn release:prepare` command, its complaining that I have local modifications to project 2 and project 3 which should be OK since it's not related to project 1 at all.
Now the question is, how do I tell the release plugin and Git to only focus on project 1 and not even bother with looking at project 2 and 3.
I'm new to GIT and have been a longtime user of SVN and never had this problem with SVN.

Answer (score 1):

With Subversion, you can check out just a subdirectory of a repository. This is not possible with Git. For a large project, this means that you always have to download the whole repository, even if you only need the current version of some sub-directory. I belive that is why release plugin is complaining about local changes in the other projects. It's a kind of general idea behind git, so the best way to work this around is to move separate projects to separate git repositories or separate [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Comment: Thanks..  I was trying to avoid creating various git repos but I guess this is the most easiest way of doing things..  thanks for the help....

Comment: You're always welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted for anyone who would face the same problem in future)

Answer (score 0):

For a quick workaround, did you try stashing the changes from projekt 2 and 3?